# find approximate mode from a list python

Tags: python, counter, python-itertools, mode

I have a list with values like `[62,62,65,67,68,69,3,3,3,1,1,30,30]`.

If I create a `Counter` using this value and take the max occurring value, I get it as 3.

But, as you can the values 62-69 are kind of close to each other, and I would like to get an average value of these values as the most occurring one. How can we achieve this in python?

Comment: maybe you could cluster your data and then look for the largest group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group your data into ranges, then find the mode
For example, arranging your data in ranges of 10, we get

```
>>> l2 = [e//10 for e in l]
>>> l2
[6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3]
```

And mode for that is 6

```
>>> Counter(l2).most_common(1)
[(6, 6)]
```

So your original data should have the mode close to middle of that range, 6*10+5 = 65